# Reformat table in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a table as below (different row with same ID will have same gender and age value but different category and sub category value):

```
  ID product.category sub.category gender   age
1  1             food      chicken      M young
2  1          kitchen       napkin      M young
3  1             food        steak      M young
4  2       electronic        phone      F   mid
5  3            cloth        shirt      M   old
6  3          kitchen         bowl      M   old
7  4             alch         beer      F young
```

And by combine different rows with same ID, I want to reform the table as below:

```
  ID product.category1 sub.category1 product.category2 sub.category2 product.category3 sub.category3 gender   age
1  1              food       chicken           kitchen        napkin              food         steak      M young
2  2        electronic         phone              null          null              null          null      F   mid
3  3             cloth         shirt           kitchen          bowl              null          null      M   old
4  4              alch          beer              null          null              null          null      F young
```

How can I do this in R?

#

New dataset:    **text variable is actually text column of notes**

```
text    Category    Subcategory variable1   variable2   variable3   variable4   date
aaaaa   c1  s11 v1  N   RETAIL  Y   2014-01
aaaaa   c2  s22 v1  N   LEASE   Y   2014-01
aaaaa   c3  s31 v1  N   LEASE   Y   2014-01
bbbbb   c1  s12 v2  N   LEASE   Y   2014-01
ccccc   c2  s21 v1  N   LEASE   Y   2014-01
ddddd   c2  s21 v1  N   RETAIL  Y   2014-01
ddddd   c3  s31 v1  N   LEASE   Y   2014-01
eeeee   c1  s11 v1  N   RETAIL  Y   2014-01
fffff   c2  s21 v2  U   RETAIL  Y   2014-01
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use a combination of `melt` and `dcast` from the package `reshape2`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
m2 <- melt(df, c("ID", "gender", "age")) %>% group_by(ID, variable) %>% 
  mutate(variable2 = paste0(variable, seq_along(value)))
newdf <- dcast(m2[!names(m2) %in% "variable"], ...~variable2, value.var="value", fill="null")
```

We first melt the original data frame by the product category and sub-category. Next using dplyr we group by the id column and product column (now called "variable" by default) and create a new column called `variable2`. This is just a paste of the category title and a running count of observations.

Now we have a new column that we can spread the data out by. We use `dcast` to go "wide" on the new variable2 column. There's also an argument called `fill` that we set equal to `"null"` telling dcast what to fill the missing values with.

---

Below we reorder the columns based on the desired output. The trick is worth noting even if it is a small one. It's interesting creating an interweaving sequence. Our output as is will order alphabetically ("p1", "p2", "p3", "s1", "s2", "s3"). We want a sequence that weaves them together. The challenge is to get something like (1,4,2,5,3,6). So we use:

```
c(rbind(1:3, 4:6))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

Cool huh? We take advantage of the fact that rbind will unwind column-wise while we enter the values by row. In our case, writing `1:3` can't help because there might be more products in the data. But we know that there are two headings "product category" and "sub-subcategory". We divide the unique values of `variable2` by 2 and use that instead.

```
n <- nrow(unique(m2[,"variable2"]))
newdf[c(1:3,(c(rbind(1:(n/2), (n/2+1):n))+3))]
#   ID gender   age product.category1 sub.category1 product.category2
# 1  1      M young              food       chicken           kitchen
# 2  2      F   mid        electronic         phone              null
# 3  3      M   old             cloth         shirt           kitchen
# 4  4      F young              alch          beer              null
#   sub.category2 product.category3 sub.category3
# 1        napkin              food         steak
# 2          null              null          null
# 3          bowl              null          null
# 4          null              null          null
```

---

**Update**

With the new data set provided, the same code structure works with the new column names.

```
m2 <- melt(df, measure.vars=c("Category", "Subcategory")) %>% group_by(text, variable) %>%
  mutate(variable2 = paste0(variable, seq_along(value)))

newdf <- dcast(m2[!names(m2) %in% "variable"], ... ~ variable2, value.var="value", fill="null")
n <- nrow(unique(m2[,"variable2"]))
newdf2 <- newdf[c(1:5, c(rbind(1:(n/2), (n/2+1):n))+5)]
newdf2
#    text variable1 variable3 variable4    date Category1 Subcategory1 Category2
# 1 aaaaa        v1     LEASE         Y 2014-01      null         null        c2
# 2 aaaaa        v1    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c1          s11      null
# 3 bbbbb        v2     LEASE         Y 2014-01        c1          s12      null
# 4 ccccc        v1     LEASE         Y 2014-01        c2          s21      null
# 5 ddddd        v1     LEASE         Y 2014-01      null         null        c3
# 6 ddddd        v1    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c2          s21      null
# 7 eeeee        v1    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c1          s11      null
# 8 fffff        v2    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c2          s21      null
#   Subcategory2 Category3 Subcategory3
# 1          s22        c3          s31
# 2         null      null         null
# 3         null      null         null
# 4         null      null         null
# 5          s31      null         null
# 6         null      null         null
# 7         null      null         null
# 8         null      null         null
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! very detail and understandable : )

Comment: Hi Pierre, I tried you code and it has giving me error as "Error: unknown column 'variable'" ,     here is my code "m3 <- melt(output1, c("text", "VEH_MAKE_NM", "NEW_USED_CD","PRODUCT","OVERALL_SUBV_IND","AS_OF_DATE")) %>% group_by(text, variable) %>% 
  mutate(variable2 = paste0(variable, seq_along(value)))" Thanks

Comment: Did some modification and now it seems alright for above problem... but I got a error "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.6 Gb", It is weird since it should not be this large......

Comment: I tried a some subset and it generated output.... But there is something weird that for some records, it even has category100, but the category1-99 are all blank, do you know why I got the wrong result? thanks

Comment: It's very difficult to determine what is wrong without the actual data. Can you post representative samples?

Comment: I don't know how to enter the table in comments........I will update the new input in the question. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89721/discussion-between-karl-tian-and-pierre-lafortune).

Comment: Putting the results in the comments doesn't help. I can't understand what is being displayed.

Comment: @KarlTian what would you like me to do after solving both of your examples?

Comment: by running your code I got result, is that possible,for your result's row 1 and row 5, the category 1,2,3 goes like row1: c2, c3,na row1: c2, c3,na which means regardless the sequence of non-null value categories, put them all before 'NA'? and Also for the subcategory, can we put all non-na value before 'na' in each row? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**data.table dcast** You could use `dcast` from the reshape2 or data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)

DT[, obsno := 1:.N, by=ID]
res <- dcast(DT, ID+gender+age~obsno, value.var=c("product.category","sub.category"))
```

which gives

```
   ID gender   age product.category_1 product.category_2 product.category_3 sub.category_1 sub.category_2 sub.category_3
1:  1      M young               food            kitchen               food        chicken         napkin          steak
2:  2      F   mid         electronic                 NA                 NA          phone             NA             NA
3:  3      M   old              cloth            kitchen                 NA          shirt           bowl             NA
4:  4      F young               alch                 NA                 NA           beer             NA             NA
```

To see the columns in your desired order, you could do something like

```
res[, c(1:3,4,7,5,8,6,9), with=FALSE]
```

A similar approach is probably possible with the tidyr package (though it won't be called "dcast").

I'd suggest sticking to long format (what you had originally) for any analysis. This wide format that you're looking for is very cumbersome for anything but browsing the data.

---

*Second example* For the OP's second example, I would do

```
DT2[, obsno := 1:.N, by=text]
dcast(DT2, ...~obsno, value.var=c("Category", "Subcategory"))
```

copying the `...~` trick from @PierreLafortune's answer. The result is

```
    text variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4    date Category_1 Category_2 Category_3 Subcategory_1 Subcategory_2 Subcategory_3
1: aaaaa        v1         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01         NA         c2         c3            NA           s22           s31
2: aaaaa        v1         N    RETAIL         Y 2014-01         c1         NA         NA           s11            NA            NA
3: bbbbb        v2         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01         c1         NA         NA           s12            NA            NA
4: ccccc        v1         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01         c2         NA         NA           s21            NA            NA
5: ddddd        v1         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01         NA         c3         NA            NA           s31            NA
6: ddddd        v1         N    RETAIL         Y 2014-01         c2         NA         NA           s21            NA            NA
7: eeeee        v1         N    RETAIL         Y 2014-01         c1         NA         NA           s11            NA            NA
8: fffff        v2         U    RETAIL         Y 2014-01         c2         NA         NA           s21            NA            NA
```

Comment: Hi Frank, when I try your code, it gave me errors as:"Error: value.var (product.categorysub.category) not found in input" or "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds"    Here is my code, please let me know how should I modify it: "setDT(output)

output[, obsno := 1:.N, by=text]
res <- dcast(output, text+VEH_MAKE_NM+NEW_USED_CD+PRODUCT+OVERALL_SUBV_IND+AS_OF_DATE~obsno, value.var=c("Category","Subcategory"))"    Thanks

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why it fails there. You could try it on a smaller subset of your data, like `output2 <- output[1:10]`, and just look at `dcast(output2, text~obsno, value.var=c("Category","Subcategory"))` on its own to diagnose where the code fails.

Comment: I select only 10 rows as output1 and tried this, still doesn't work....I will update my question with the new detail.... please take a look then. Thanks

Comment: Hi Frank, I updated new table format(the one I tired code on but didn't work) in the question... Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: @KarlTian I have added code for the new case you posted. It seems to work.

Comment: `setDT(output)

output[, obsno := 1:.N, by=text]
output1<-output[1:100,]
res <- dcast(output1, text+variable1+variable2+variable3+variable4+date~obsno, value.var=c("Category","Subcategory"))
`    Please try mine to see if it works or has some mistake.... thanks    And what did you mean of the "...~" trick... Is that mean you can use"..." instead of typing all the variables names by default? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just meant using `...` instead of typing it out; I didn't know that that was an option until I saw it in Pierre's answer. Yours works fine for me with the example given, but I do not have your full `output` object and so can't subset to the first 100 rows.

Comment: Hi Frank..... I tried several times with small subset and it still throw me same error "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds", Please see below code: `setDT(output)

output[, obsno := 1:.N, by=text]
output1<-output[1:2,]
res <- dcast(output1, ...~obsno, value.var=c("Category","Subcategory"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89722/discussion-between-frank-and-karl-tian).

Comment: My company has blocked the chat web page.... Can I have your email instead? thanks

Comment: @KarlTian Sorry, I'm not up for that. I was just suggesting that you post a new question with a reproducible example.

Comment: `> output[, obsno := 1:.N, by=text]
> output1<-output[1:50,]
> res <- dcast(output1, ...~obsno, value.var=c("Category","Subcategory"))
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
` Here is what I got.....

Answer (score 4):

An alternative with `dplyr` & `tidyr`:

```
newdf <- df %>% gather(variable, value, product.category, sub.category) %>%
  group_by(ID, variable) %>%
  mutate(variable2 = paste0(variable, seq_along(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  spread(variable2 , value)
```

which gives:

```
> newdf
Source: local data frame [4 x 9]

     ID gender    age product.category1 product.category2 product.category3 sub.category1 sub.category2 sub.category3
  (int) (fctr) (fctr)             (chr)             (chr)             (chr)         (chr)         (chr)         (chr)
1     1      M  young              food           kitchen              food       chicken        napkin         steak
2     2      F    mid        electronic                NA                NA         phone            NA            NA
3     3      M    old             cloth           kitchen                NA         shirt          bowl            NA
4     4      F  young              alch                NA                NA          beer            NA            NA
```

---

The same can be done on the second example dataset:

```
newdat <- dat %>% gather(variable, value, Category, Subcategory) %>%
  group_by(text, variable) %>%
  mutate(var2 = paste0(variable, seq_along(value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-variable) %>%
  spread(var2 , value)
```

which gives:

```
> newdat
Source: local data frame [8 x 12]

    text variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4    date Category1 Category2 Category3 Subcategory1 Subcategory2 Subcategory3
  (fctr)    (fctr)    (fctr)    (fctr)    (fctr)  (fctr)     (chr)     (chr)     (chr)        (chr)        (chr)        (chr)
1  aaaaa        v1         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01        NA        c2        c3           NA          s22          s31
2  aaaaa        v1         N    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c1        NA        NA          s11           NA           NA
3  bbbbb        v2         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01        c1        NA        NA          s12           NA           NA
4  ccccc        v1         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01        c2        NA        NA          s21           NA           NA
5  ddddd        v1         N     LEASE         Y 2014-01        NA        c3        NA           NA          s31           NA
6  ddddd        v1         N    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c2        NA        NA          s21           NA           NA
7  eeeee        v1         N    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c1        NA        NA          s11           NA           NA
8  fffff        v2         U    RETAIL         Y 2014-01        c2        NA        NA          s21           NA           NA
```

Comment: @KarlTian see the updated answer, now it also includes a solution for your second (new) dataset

Comment: Thanks Jaap: ) will try it

Comment: Hi Jaap, @Jaap, I tried yours and it works.... But I want something different in the result is that: for row 1 and row 5, is that possible the category 1,2,3 goes like `row1: c2, c3,na`  `row1: c2, c3,na` which means regardless the sequence of non-null value categories, put them all before 'NA'? Thanks

Comment: @KarlTian I'm not completely sure what you mean, but you can change the order of the observations in the dataframe with for example `arrange(Category1, Category2, Category3)`. This will first order the `newdat` by `Category1`, then by `Category2` and finally by `Category3`.