# Rearranging a table based on a certain condition and using for loop

Tags: r

I will start directly with the code, this should make it clear as to what the objective is:

```
library(gapminder)    
head(gapminder)

    # A tibble: 6 x 6
  country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
  <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.
2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.
3 Afghanistan Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.
4 Afghanistan Asia       1967    34.0 11537966      836.
5 Afghanistan Asia       1972    36.1 13079460      740.
6 Afghanistan Asia       1977    38.4 14880372      786.
```

Saving the country names in another variable:

```
y <- unique(gapminder$country, incomparables = FALSE)
    length(y)
    [1] 142
    df.names <- paste(y, sep = "")
```

Expected output:

I want to have 142 columns +1 for `year` and only the `pop` values. The code that I am trying is this:

```
for(i in 1:length(y)){
  d.frame[,i] <- gapminder$pop %>% filter(gapminder$country==y[i])
  assign(df.names[i], d.frame)
}
```

This code is trying to assign the `pop` value corresponding to each `year` in the rows and the column's name is its corresponding `country`. The `year` has not been used in the code because I am adding the value later on and right now just selecting `country` and `pop` values based on the condition. Since the years in this table are repeating, **I want that column to be present just once (later on). So, the final table must have be 12*143 table (12 rows and 143 columns).** This is not working.

Any ideas? I would also appreciate any suggestions pertaining to the design and structure if needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reformat table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570473/reformat-table-in-r)

Comment: Hey, edited the question to make it more clear. The requirement here is a little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
gapminder %>%
    select(country, pop, year) %>%
    spread(country, pop)
```

This gives you one row per year, and one column per country, containing its population in that year.

(`spread` is part of the {tidyr} package.)